# Pandas Drop Duplicates Between Two Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for efficient way to drop duplicates between two columns in Pandas data frame. So, my data is,

```
   A  B 
0  1  0  
1  1  1  
2  nan  2  
3  8  3
4  7  7
```

I want to get that,

```
   A  B 
0  1  0  
1 nan  2  
2  8  3
```

How can I get output like that? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = df[df.A != df.B]
```

Using a loop as requested:

```
dups_index = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['A'] == row['B']:
        dups_index.append(i)
df = df[~df.index.isin(dups_index)]
```

Comment: It works but I think, it's not efficient that much. :(

Comment: I'm sorry. If you find a more efficient approach, let me know :)

Comment: Do this in a loop is probably not more efficient. But I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: I don't know of any faster way to do this. The original answer of `df = df[df.A != df.B]` should be immensely faster than a loop.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!!

Comment: For 10000x2 elements the first solution is about 1500 times faster than the second one...